# Split string by specific symbol

Tags: cmd

I need to convert string (time) to seconds

`Set Time=01:00:00` (hh:mm:ss)

So I need somehow split my string first by ":" to get three variables and then just convert hours & minutes to seconds and make sum of all three variables

is it possible with cmd to split variable like this?

Answer (score 1):

- `%time%`is an automatic variable returning the time in an localized/user defined format.
- There may be leading spaces in the hour and leading zeroes in the minutes and seconds.
- causing problems when multiplying with set /A because a leading zero denotes an octal number.

---

```
> echo %time%  
 1:27:02,43
```

As you can see there is a leading space and appended 100th seconds.
You can circumvent some of the problems using wmic to get the localtim in ISO format.

```
> wmic os get LocalDateTime /value|find "="
LocalDateTime=20170526015233.985000+120
```

To  parse datetime from that output and calculate total seconds:

```
@Echo off
For /f "tokens=2delims==." %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime /value^|find "="'
) do set DT=%%A
set /A hh=1%DT:~-6,2%-100,mm=1%DT:~-4,2%-100,ss=1%DT:~-2%-100
Echo hh=%hh% mm=%mm% ss=%ss%
Set /A TotalSecs=hh*3600+mm*60+ss
Echo Elapsed seconds since midnight %TotalSecs%
```

Sample output:

```
 2:08:38 > ElapsedSecs.cmd
hh=2 mm=8 ss=38
Elapsed seconds since midnight 7718
```